# Get current folder for a Blazor Server website hosted in another service?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I need to get the file location for the running Blazor Server Webpage hosted in another c# service. I have tried these so far :

```
var test = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var test1 = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var test2 = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            var test3 = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            var test4 = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var test5 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var test6 = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var test7 = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;
```

None of them works? most are just empty, some of them contains '/'.

Comment: test4 should work for the currently running process ... I'd think you'd have to provide something for service1, from service2? to be sure.

Comment: The hosting service is a regular Console Application that creates a WeApplicationBuilder\WebApplication based of the main Blazor webproject and then starts it. I suspect that this console app service could in some cases be excluded so it seems unreliable to provide any data to the blazor project from here?